# How can I sort a table with one-time binding in angularJS and maintain modal speed?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat loop with clickable, sorting headers. However, there was some extreme latency introduced around 150 elements, with a total of 8000+ watchers. However, if I increase the speed by using one-time binding, I lose the ability to sort.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="ManageHeader">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="vm.changeSort('stack_name')">Stack Name
                    <span ng-if="sortType === 'stack_name' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                    <span ng-if="sortType === 'stack_name' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                  </a></th>
                <th class="ManageHeader">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="vm.changeSort('date')">Create Date
                    <span ng-if="sortType === 'date' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                    <span ng-if="sortType === 'date' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                  </a></th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="min-height-table" ng-repeat-start="stack in ::vm.stackList | orderBy:vm.customSort:sortReverse" ng-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">
```

...
Note the :: in "::vm.stackList". This removes my sortability but increases speed.
Alternatives?

One of the properties of each 'stack' is a deploy button that opens a modal. Within the modal is where the worst slow-down happens. The modal opens a form for the user to add some more details, where the worst slow down happens. Alternatives?

Comment: Why don't you use one-time binding inside the repeated template? I mean the multiple properties of `stack`. You can't avoid binding to main data source

Comment: show how the full `ng-repeat-start` / `ng-repeat-end` is structured. Also there are lots of readily available grid/table modules around with good performance

Comment: I guess I need to give more information. See above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: the reason for the slowness was in my customSort function, which included sorting by date. In order to do so, I was calling
switch(sortVar):
.
.
.
case 'date':
return -1*moment(--formatted date here--).unix();

Although this was the clean way to do it, it was also the slow way. Instead, I created a new element of the 'stack' object called dateIndex and used that instead (since the stacks are received initially in date order). Again, this isn't a smart programmatic way to do it, but it helped with my speed.